# Datetime current_timestamp in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, datetime, mariadb

I've finished the first version of my site, and I'm now ready to move it from my local development environment (MySQL) to my x10hosting server (they use MariaDB).

I'm able to move all my files over fine, but the issues started happening when I moved the database over.

I exported my database as a .sql file from phpmyadmin on my local machine, and opened phpmyadmin on x10 to import the file, but it throws this error:

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'created'
```

I traced the issue to it being that 'created' is a datetime type, and apparently MariaDB doesn't let you set current_timestamp as a default for datetime.

How can I use the current timestamp as the datetime default in maria?

The full create statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `comments` (
   `id` BIGINT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   `post` BIGINT( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
   `author` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
   `comment` TEXT NOT NULL ,
   `mod_status` INT( 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  '0 is needing moderation,   1 is approved, and 2 is rejected',
   `created` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
   PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =4;
```

Comment: What versions of MySQL and MariaDB is running?

Comment: it should work...can we see the entire create table statement?  Have you tried `Now()`?

Comment: Now is a synonym for current_timestamp. He is looking for datetime (not timestamp).

Comment: @wchiquito x10 is running MariaDB 5.5.44, and on my local machine I'm running MySQL 5.6.16

Answer (score 1):

In MariaDB you must refer to `DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP` as a function `()` :

```sql
`created` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
                                                     ^^
```

Then it will work. Have noticed the same peculiarity when firing INSERT statements using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `NOW`. In MySQL you can do

```sql
insert into table (created, id) values ('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 42)
```

in MariaDB it must be

```sql
insert into table (created, id) values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 42)
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess your column is of type datetime and not timestamp, so you should use

```
current_date
```

Have a look at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/current_date/

Comment: Since [MariaDB 10.0.1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1001-release-notes/), DATETIME columns also accept [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/now/) as the default value. - [DATETIME](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/datetime/).

Comment: I tried current_date, but it throws the error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_date , PRIMARY KEY ( id ) ) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin' at line 8`

Comment: @wchiquito  x10 is running MariaDB 5.5.44, so unfortunately I can't use it. I may contact them and see if they'll update it

Comment: Can you use it in Upper, like `CURRENT_DATE`?